# Why would you combine two 32 bit integers into a 64 bit integer?

Tags: c++, c

Recently I saw how a compiler combined two 32 bit integers which were values of properties of a class and stored them as a 64 bit integer. My question now is, why is this done? What advantages are there when combining integers?

for example if we had the following properties of a class

```
class FooBar {
 int x = 1;
 int y = 100;
}
```

so instead of

```
i32 = 00000001
i32 = 01100100
```

We get:

```
i64 = 0000000101100100
```

Why would you combine them?

Comment: My guess is that the register uses 64 bits. It's using just one register to store both instead of using two registers.

Comment: Why not? If the machine works more efficiently with 64 bit integers it may be a win.. in any case; why do you care?

Comment: CPUs don't generally have types. Something like `int` is a property of your program, not of the resulting machine code. It's not really appropriate to call this "combining", because the before and after are parts of completely different domains.

Comment: If the machine uses 64 bits register & mem system, then it's kind of a waste of space to use 32 bits variables, hence the merge of the two variable. The draw back, however is that operations on these variables will take a bit longer, as they'll have to be AND'ed with 0x00FF and 0xFF00 (+ shift) when you want to work with them, most probably

Comment: @Maliafo nice explanation!

Comment: Shame it wasn't in the answer section where it belongs.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition indeed

Comment: Can you give an example showing the actual "combining" you are referring to? For example, if you noted it in the generated assembly, provide the assembly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The existing (as I write this) answer and comments, while partially correct, miss the point of this optimization.  It is to replace two instructions (working with 32-bit data) with one instruction (working with 64-bit data).  This results in a very slight reduction in code size and probably execution time.

The compiler is initializing both variables with one 64-bit instruction (since they share consecutive memory addresses).  The variables are separate, and will be accessed separately.  No shifting or masking is needed.

This is frequently seen in constructors when many members are initialized.  A frequent case is with zero initialization, where the compiler will zero out a register then use that one value to initialize multiple members, combining writes to consecutive memory addresses with a larger single write (for example, by writing a 16-bit short zero value instead of two 8-bit ones).

Comment: Accepted your answer since I feel it is far more complete.

Comment: This a perfect answer, seriously. Thanks

Comment: >  No shifting or masking is needed.

I disagree with that point. You must alias the memory space to use 4 byte alignment. See this link: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/coding-for-performance-data-alignment-and-structures

That said, I think you are correct that aliasing an address as 32 or 64 is near-"free" regarding performance. Nice answer.

Comment: @Sam The optimizer sees a 4 byte write to address A, followed immediately by a 4 byte write to address (A+4).  These are combined into an 8 byte write to address A.  _No other changes to the code are necessary or made._  If there were issues with alignment or aliasing this optimization would not be made.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you're observing an optimization. Intel instructions such as `PADDSW` assume multiple packed operands.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings

There are also benefits in only using 1 entry in a 64bit architecture cache.

There is a cost to unpack if you only want one of the values, but I suspect whatever code optimizer is running estimates there are better savings pack the values.

It used to be normal to align all members of a C struct onto a word boundary. That is a single `char` and an `int` would not be packed, but aligned to the word size of the machine. So, `struct { char, int}` would have a `sizeof(..)` of 8 bytes. I'm guessing that situation flipped?

Very interesting.

Comment: You probably heared of webassembly right? They are doing it there. What you are saying is really interesting

Comment: The `PAD…` instructions are for SIMD.  They packed values are all of the same type.  There is no cost to unpack, as the individual values still have normal addresses.